# Cannot copy intermediate docker container files to host

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile, it does dotnet publish and the dll's are copied to intermediate docker container. I would like to copy the dll's which are generated in container to my local system (Host) as well.

I believe we can use "cp" command to do that, but I am not able to find a solution to get the intermediate container Id to use the "cp" command.

syntax: docker cp CONTAINER:Container_Path Host_Path.

Please suggest me any other better solution for this scenario.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1.4 as builder

COPY . /Code

RUN dotnet restore /Code/MyProj.csproj
RUN dotnet publish -c Release  /Code/MyProj.csproj
RUN cp CONTAINER: /Code/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/publish  /binaries
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you restoring and publishing in your dockerfile?  Why not have your copy step copy the binaries in directly?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is outside of the Dockerfile.
first your Dockerfile would have to have a volume.
[VOLUME] /my/path/in/container

To get files into and out of a volume, try using tar -cvf and tar -xvf to put and get files between a container and a host.

To put files from host's newfiles.tar in pwd to a container at /var/lib/neo4j/conf mount.

```
docker run --rm \
-v my-volume-data:/my/path/in/container -v $(pwd):/newfiles ubuntu bash -c \
"cd /my/path/in/container && tar -xf /newfiles/newfiles.tar"
```

To get files from into a container at /my/path/in/container mount to a host oldfiles.tar.

```
docker run --rm \
-v my-volume-data:/my/path/in/container -v $(pwd):/newfiles ubuntu bash -c \
"cd /my/path/in/container && tar -cf /newfiles/origfiles.tar"
```

The `--user 1000:1000` is optional if your container has a user with uid of 1000.